# How to reach this element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="ptp-item-container">
    <div class="plan">Text I want!</div>
    <div class="price">200</div>
    <div class="bullet-item">some other text</div>
    <div class="cta"> <a class="button" href="javascript:getText()">Go!</a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

From the button I tried this:

```
function getText(){
  alert($(this).parent().parent().children().text() );
}
```

This doesnt really work, I know there is a way! It's important to use $(this) for this time.

Edit: This is the whole Javascript:

```
<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
        $(".ptp-button").attr("href", "javascript:getText()");
  });
        function getText(){
            alert($(this).closest('.ptp-item-container').find('.plan').text());
        }
</script>
```

But the console says "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function VM4092:1(anonymous function)"

Dont I have to give $(this) as an argument on javascript:getText($(this)) or something like this?

Comment: Why not use `.on()` for the click handler instead of having the href call js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be targeting it with `javascript:` href. Instead, use an `.on()` handler, that is the correct way to handle the click event on JQuery. Then you'll be able to use the `this` reference:

Then, as already answered, instead of navigation through the parents, use the `.closest()` function:

```
$('.ptp-item-container').on('click', '.button', function() {
    alert($(this).closest(".ptp-item-container").find(".plan").text());
});
```

Comment: i think your selector should be ".ptp-item-container a.button"

Comment: @Heraldmonkey Nope, look again. They are selecting it. More about the way they are selecting it [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Yes @Heraldmonkey, but it works just the same. It's only a way of being sure that the anchor is wrapped inside a `.ptp-item-container` element

Comment: Thank you. This works perfect. I have to use .on() !

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `.closest()` and `.find()`:

```
alert($(this).closest(".ptp-item-container").find(".plan").text());
```

It pays to spend some time browsing [the jQuery API documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: Sorry correct fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/u68vv1yu/1/ `$(this)` does not refer to the anchor